# simple php function to do complected math?

Tags: php, math

I need a simple function to do some math for my inputs to generate max number of fixed values .. 
i know its all about the math not the function itself but i have no idea how to create this kind of math .. 
Below i wrote a simple logic for the math 
lets say we have an object that will cost fixed numbers of 4 elements like this

```
<?php
$a = 140 ;
$b = 180 ;
$c= 85 ;
$d = 110 ;
?>
```

and 4 inputs like this :

```
<?php
$w = 14000 ;
$x = 1000 ;
$y = 800 ;
$z = 1100 ;
?>
```

if we compare the cost of the object to the inputs we will notice that for $a vs $w we may create 10 objects ..
but for $b vs $x it can't create more than 5 objects .
what i need to do is to distribute or separate the numbers in the 4 inputs between each others to get the max result of the first 4 values .
actually i don't know if there is some pre-defined function within PHP to do this or should i create some math manually . 
and if not i will need any ideas to create this kind of math

**Updates**
i got this formula from stockoverflow math site but have no idea how to apply it in PHP ..
[image]

Comment: Have you got any formula?

Comment: @sectus this is the problem i have no idea for any formula :)

Comment: `floor($w/$a)` will produce how many of one that you can get with the other - cutting off excess.

Comment: Also, unless you are going for efficiency for money on hand, the lowest number of the first result set will always yield the most items from the second. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Something like this work for ya?

```
$costs = array(140,180,85,110);
$avaliable = array(14000,1000,800,1100);
$i = 0;  
while($i < count($costs)):
$max[] = floor($avaliable[$i]/$costs[$i]);
$i++;
endwhile;
```

Output: Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 5 [2] => 9 [3] => 10 )

Comment: It will run through the array of values you are comparing then output the results into an array.

Comment: yes i know its comparing inputs with values but what i need is a different thing i want distribute inputs between each others to generate the max number of required object

Comment: What I gave you processes the Equation you have on your update. If you want something different then can you show me the process you want converted into PHP in equation form.